# list display in choicEntity in symfony 5

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I am not at all familiar with PHP, and still months with Symfony, I am developing a small project thanks to a tutorial and I have a problem that has blocked me for too long
veil: I have a `choiceType` on a form which must display a list that comes from an array passed in the parameters of the `createForm`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $choices = $options['choices'];
    $builder
        -> add ('month', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $choices,
      ]);
}
```

My array comes from

```
$months = $tagtimeRepository->group_month($chron); 
$choice = array(); 
foreach($months as $lang){ 
    $code = $lang->getMonth(); 
    $choice[] = $code; 
}
```

So here it is, the list displays `0, 1, 2, ...`, but I would like to see `11, 8, 9, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As prompted in the documentation

> The `choices` option is an array, **where the array key is the item’s label and the array value is the item’s value**

<sup>*Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices, emphasis, mine*</sup>

So you just have to swap your keys and values in your array and you should be good to go:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder->add('month', ChoiceType::class, [
         'choices' => [
             '11' => '0',
             '8'  => '1',
             '9'  => '3',
         ],
     ]);
 }
```

---

If you do get those values in this way from a database, as you prompted it later, you can still use [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) in order to have the array in the correct way:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     /**
      * array_flip would flip keys and value, effectively making the array 
      * [
      *      '11' => '0',
      *      '8'  => '1',
      *      '9'  => '3',
      * ]
      * out of 
      * [
      *      '0' => '11',
      *      '1' => '8',
      *      '3' => '9',
      * ]
      **/
     $builder->add('month', ChoiceType::class, [
         'choices' => array_flip($options['choices']),
     ]);
 }
```

Comment: the table is fed by a bdd, I cannot reverse the values

Comment: This is not what you show in your question, where it comes from a function.

Comment: Either way, `array_flip` can help you do this, see updated answer

Comment: sorry, this was example to have the format code, the table is filled as continuation
$ months = $ tagtimeRepository-> group_month ($ chron);
        
         $ choice = array ();
         foreach ($ months as $ lang) {
             $ code = $ lang-> getMonth ();
             $ choice [] = $ code;
         }

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64809127/edit) this in your question rather than adding it in a comment, because this is quite an important piece of information to answer you.

Comment: indeed, it displays the values well, on the other hand once I submit, I retrieve the keys, there is a way once to retrieve the data in with "$ month = $ form ['month'] -> getdata ( ); " to reverse them again ??